# Passing via GET json to ajax jquery,

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm getting from a php page a json after a json encode. I correctly see the json in page that i want to pass to ajax. The data i send are taken via get from a form in php, saved in an array and then passsed with json encode.

But i get the error object from ajax:

[image: ajax error code]

What i'm missing? Should i copy and paste part of my backend too?

```
$.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "queries/queries.php",
            dataType: "json",
            succes: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log('json found');
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
                console.log('json not found');
            }
          });
```

backend:

```
            $calls= "text";

           for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) { 

            $schemaTab = $array[$i] . $calls;
   
            $query = "SELECT * from 'schema'.'table'"; // this is just a sample query

            $res=$db->getQuery($query); // this is a function that output the db query
            header('Content-Type: application/json');

            echo json_encode($res); // the json i pass
        }
```

json:

```
[{"Schema":"schemaName1","DATEHOUR":"10\/05\/2021 11:56","count":"4"}] 
[{"Schema":"schemaName2","DATEHOUR":"10\/05\/2021 10:21","count":"3"}] 
[{"Schema":"schemaName3","DATEHOUR":null,"count":"0"}] 
[{"Schema":"schemaName4","DATEHOUR":null,"count":"0"}]
```

Comment: Share the php code and sample json in it also. Helps in quicker resolution.

Comment: I see statusCode 200 a text="OK", it isn't error message. In your code I see just a typo, `succes` vs. `success`.

Comment: You're not sending any `data` in the request and `succes` needs to be `success`. Voting to close as the problem is caused by typos.

Comment: I corrected the typo of success but still not getting the data. I'm copy and pasting the backedn wait 2 mins. Thank you.

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. JSON must consist of *one thing* such an a string, object, or array. (Objects and arrays can nest as many other things as they like inside them).

You have an array (`[{"Schema":"schemaName1","DATEHOUR":"10\/05\/2021 11:56","count":"4"}]`) which would be valid JSON but then you have **another array** and so on.

Gather up all your data into a variable in your PHP.

Then have `header('Content-Type: application/json'); echo json_encode($that_variable)` **once, outside the loop**.